# Getting Datasource instance which is configured in Application Server?

Tags: java, datasource, cdi, jndi, jboss-eap-6

I have configured a Datasource in JBOSS EAP 6.3.2 using Admin console.

I want to know what are the ways in which we can get the instance of this Datasource? Can we use `@Resouce` , `@Inject` annotations to get the Datasource?

Or should we use the old JNDI lookup?

Can anyone please help me understand this?

Comment: Do you really need the datasource and not a entityManager?

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Jboss EAP but as it's a Java EE 6 Server, you should be able to inject your datasource through `@Resource` annotation.

If it works the same as JBOSS AS 7, you should :

- Define your datasource in `standalone.xml`
- Inject the datasource specifying the `lookup` attribute of `@Resource`

```java
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/MyDataSource")
private DataSource m_dataSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using weblogic and I am using the lookup for getting connection. 
This may help you.

```
public Connection getConnection(){
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    Connection connection = null;
        try {
                InitialContext initContext;
                initContext = new InitialContext();
                dataSource = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("jdbc/MyDatasource");
            try {
                connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    return connection;
}
```